# Is it possible to attach cookie to script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

There's a script I'm fetching via dynamically adding a script tag. The script content sent back varies depending on the value of a certain cookie (say, `server`) in the GET request for fetching the script.

I know that GET request for a `<script>` will automatically carry all (permitted) cookies set in browser along with it. Can I add some of my own cookie values to this request in code?

The code I'm using is similar to this:

```js
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'https://example.com/script';
script.onload = () => console.log("Loaded!");
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: No, a cookie is sent in a http header (both request from client to server and response from server to client) - it's all part of privacy and security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the cookie before the .src statement, it will be sent to the server IIF the server is the same as from where the page was loaded.

You cannot set a cookie on domainA that is sent to domainB regardless that you can load a script from domainB

NOTE: The correct order is this - ALWAYS set the load handler BEFORE setting the src of anything; the server can respond with the file before the next statement is read.

Also we normally append the script to the head. This will also work after the page has loaded.

```
// change cookie here
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.onload = () => console.log("Loaded!");
// or change cookie here
script.src = 'https://example.com/script';
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick answer! Any reason why the load handler should be set before setting src? Also, if I'm using React (so the whole page HTML is probably already loaded), does it make a difference to add the script in the head?

Comment: In your simple case likely not, but on a really fast network, the script may load and trigger the handler before you replaced it. Yes you can append to the head after load